# Traefik v2 and routing with path

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, traefik

I tried this:

```
version: "3.3"                                                                          
services:                                                                               
  traefik:                                                                              
    image: "traefik:latest"                                                             
    command:                                                                            
      - --api.insecure=true                                                             
      - --providers.docker=true                                                         
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false                                       
      - --api=true                                                                      
      - --api.dashboard=true                                                            
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80                                                   
      - --log.filePath=/home/docker/traefik.log                                         
      - --log.level=DEBUG                                                               
    ports:                                                                              
      - "80:80"                                                                         
      - "8080:8080"                                                                     
    volumes:                                                                            
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"                                  

  whoami:                                                                               
    image: "containous/whoami"                                                          
    labels:                                                                             
      - "traefik.enable=true"                                                           
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.traefik.kb`) && Path(`/who`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"                                   
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.service=whoami"                                    
      - "traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80"                      
  nginx:                                                                                
    image: "nginx:alpine"                                                               
    labels:                                                                             
      - "traefik.enable=true"                                                           
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`nginx.traefik.kb`) && Path(`/ng`)"       
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web"                                    
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.service=nginx"                                      
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80"                       
  nginx2:                                                                               
    image: "nginx:alpine"                                                               
    labels:                                                                             
      - "traefik.enable=true"                                                           
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.rule=Host(`nginx2.traefik.kb`)"                    
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.entrypoints=web"                                   
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.service=nginx2"                                    
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx2.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

I use this stack in docker swarm. My problem is when I try to reach **nginx.traefik.kb/ng** and i get 404 from nginx. With the whoami image and the url **whoami.traefik.kb/who** i dont have any problem and with **nginx2.traefik.kb** neither...

I only have this config file, no traefik.yml or so.

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: You will want to also put a strip prefix middleware on that route as traefik does not automatically do that for you.  https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/

Comment: You help me to understand better the preffixes. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED!

Adding this:

```
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.nginx-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/ng"
  - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.middlewares=nginx-prefix"
```

With this I cant go to http://example.com/ng and get nginx running